# "Variable might not have been initialized" -- Text Based Adventure in Java

Tags: java, variables, initialization

So I'm trying to create a text-based adventure. It starts in a room, and gives you two room options. From there, each room option has 2 more options. And then each room has a "yes" or "no" option..

There are a total of 15 rooms, and 8 different outcomes. I am supposed to be creating this using if statements.  However I keep getting an error that says "variable may not have been initalized" for the variables room2, room3, room4, room5, room6, & room7.  I know that it is because the variables are declared within the if statement, but I do not know the correct solution.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Adventure1
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String room1, room2, room3, room4, room5, room6, room7;

        System.out.println( "Welcome to Carolyn's Tiny Adventure! " );
        System.out.println( "You are in a SUPER creepy house! " );
        System.out.println( "Do you want to go upstairs or into the basement ? " );
        System.out.println( "(upstairs OR basement)" );
        room1 = keyboard.next();

        if ( room1.equals("upstairs") )
        {
            System.out.println( "You notice there is a ladder that leads to an attic." );
            System.out.println( "Do you want to go up or explore the bedrooms? (up OR bedrooms) " );
            room2 = keyboard.next();
        }

        if ( room1.equals("basement") )
        {
        System.out.println( "There's nothing in the basement except an old rocking chair & a dusty     cabinet. " );
        System.out.println( "Do you want to open or would you rather rock on the chair? (open OR chair) " );
        room3 = keyboard.next();
    }

    if ( room2.equals("up") )
    {
        System.out.println( "It's super dark up here, & there's dust and spiders everywhere. " );
        System.out.println( "But you see a cool looking chest. Do you want to open it? (yes OR no) " );
        room4 = keyboard.next();
    }

    if ( room2.equals("bedrooms") ) 
    {
        System.out.println( "You find what looks like a child's bedroom. " );
        System.out.println( "Do you want to see what's inside the closet? (yes OR no) " );
        room5 = keyboard.next();
    }

    if ( room3.equals("open") )
    {
        System.out.println( "Inside the chest is an opaque jar. You can't tell what's inside. " );
        System.out.println( "Do you want to open it? (yes OR no) " );
        room6 = keyboard.next();
    }

    if ( room3.equals("chair") )
    {
        System.out.println( "You're walking over to sit on the chair & you notice it's a little sideways." );
        System.out.println( "Do you want to sit on it anyway? (yes OR no) " );
        room7 = keyboard.next();
    }

    if ( room4.equals("yes") )
    {
        System.out.println( "Uh-oh! You've been bit by a black widow." );
        System.out.println( "Thanks for playing with me!!!" );
    }

    if ( room4.equals("no") )
    {
        System.out.println( "Welp, I guess you'll never know what was inside!" );
        System.out.println( "Thanks for playing with me!!!" );
    }

    if ( room5.equals("yes") )
    {
        System.out.println( "YIKES! There's a creepy doll staring at you." );
        System.out.println( "That image may never leave your mind... " );
        System.out.println( "Thanks for playing with me!!! " );
    }

    if ( room5.equals("no") )
    {
        System.out.println( "I guess you'll never know what was inside... " );
        System.out.println( "Thanks for playing with me!!! " );
    }

    if ( room6.equals("yes") )
    {
        System.out.println( "EW! There's a rotting bird in there! You just threw up. " );
        System.out.println( "Thanks for playing with me!!! " );
    }

    if ( room6.equals("no") )
    {
        System.out.println( "You'll never know what was inside! Your loss! " );
        System.out.println( "Thanks for playing with me!!! " );
    }

    if ( room7.equals("yes") )
    {
        System.out.println( "When you sat down it fell apart! Now dust is all over your butt. Whoops." );
        System.out.println( "Thanks for playing with me!!! " );
    }

    if ( room7.equals("no") )
    {
        System.out.println( "Smart choice! It looks like that thing was going to fall apart any second." );
        System.out.println( "Thanks for playing with me!!! " );
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Simple: Initialize the variable that the compiler is complaining about. Give it *some* starting value, if a String, then perhaps either `null` or `""`.

Comment: You have an error in your concept: `if ( room2.equals("up") )` can easily cause a `NullPointerException` when the user not entered "upstairs". The same could happen with `room3` if the user entered something different than "basement".

Comment: If you found an answer, then don't edit your question title. Instead tick the corresponding answer as "accepted" by clicking the check mark under the vote counter.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the variables:

```
String room1, room2, room3, room4, room5, room6, room7;

String room1 = null;
String room2 = null;
String room3 = null;
String room4 = null;
String room5 = null;
String room6 = null;
String room7 = null;
```

Or Initialize to `""`

Answer (score 0):

Change your line

```
String room1, room2, room3, room4, room5, room6, room7;
```

to

```
String room1 = "", room2 = "", room3 = "", room4 = "", room5 = "", room6 = "", room7 = "";
```

Or you can assign anything else may be more relevant value like **not assigned**

```
room1 = "not assigned"
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this happens because you only guarantee to give a value to the `room1`. 
The rest of them are assigned a value inside an `if` statement. But what if the `if` statement is never `true` ? what are the values of `room2,...,room7` ?
That's why the compliler is complaining. Just initialize every variable to an empty `String` like this,
 `String room2 = ""` etc.., and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

At compile time, it'll check for all the variables, etc if they are properly initialized so that they may not create exceptions/errors at run time.
Here in your case there is a chance that it may cause Nullpointerexception at run time. So you must initialize these variables to some value or empty string.